# Which languages have tensorflow bindings similar to the eager API of tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow

I like tensorflow.js as a library but I don't want to use javascript for a project.

Besides python, which languages have a library like the eager tensorflow.js?

I think this question boils down to what the C api exposes. I heard that TF 2.0 (for python) is eager, but is the c api available for TF 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs for Tensorflow 2.0, C++ and Java are available in addition to Python.

Source for C++ API : [C++ API official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/cc)